# Does upgrading to Mountain Lion means I have to reinstall Android SDK and Eclipse?

Tags: macos, upgrade, android

I'm on Lion and am learning Android development. I have Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1 version and the lastest SDK installed.

If I upgrade to Mountain Lion does it mean I have reinstall the SDK?

I have folders in the root Macintosh HD such as android-sdk-macosx, are these deleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, nothing is deleted when updating. A common sense would be to back-up everything as things *can* go wrong, but if everything go right, nothing is deleted! Even opened apps are reopened after update.

It must be noted though that the first time you launch Eclipse, OS X will tell you that it will install Java first, as Java is not installed by default anymore.

Comment: I use Time Machine so all my files are backed up right? If something does go wrong I can just restore it?

Comment: yes, you're pretty much all set. Just go ahead. I updated 2 machine and had absolutely no problem. I'm using both XCode and Eclipse for iOS and Android dev and nothing disappeared when updated!